Error Implementing `WKScriptMessageHandler` in Swift Framework for React Native Integration
I’ve developed an iOS Swift framework (.framework) to handle WebKit functionality, which is meant to be integrated into a React Native project. To export my Swift code to React Native, I’ve utilized RCT_EXTERN_MODULE and RCT_EXTERN_METHOD. Everything was working smoothly until I added functionality for WKScriptMessageHandler (used for receiving messages from JavaScript running in a webpage).
After adding this, when I attempt to integrate the Swift framework into another iOS(React Native) project for testing purposes, I’m encountering the following error:
**Can't find Protocol Declaration for WKScriptMessageHandler**

I made sure to implement the WKScriptMessageHandler protocol correctly in my Swift code, but the error appears in the framework’s auto-generated -swift.h file:
@interface DWWebViewController : UIViewController <WKScriptMessageHandler>

**Type argument 'WKScriptMessage' must be a pointer (requires a '*')**

**Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class 'UIViewController'**

**Unknown class name 'WKScriptMessageHandler'; did you mean 'WKScriptMessage'?**

I’ve tried various approaches, but I’m not sure how to resolve this issue. Could anyone provide guidance on how to properly implement WKScriptMessageHandler in a Swift framework and avoid these errors?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

I'm running into this too with a library that I've been trying to migrate to React Native's "new architecture". Is yours using the new architecture too?
https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/landing-page

@rawbee I am not sure whether I am using the  React Native's "new architecture or not. But as I told in my question I have a .xcframework(in swift) where I am using WKScriptMessageHandler, and I am facing with the errors I shared above. What I have found is if You use Objective-c and then use WKScriptMessageHandler, the errors go away. But that's not the solution for my Problem.

After spending several days troubleshooting and experimenting with different approaches, I finally found a solution to my own issue.
To handle WKScriptMessageHandler, I used an Objective-C category, since WKScriptMessageHandler doesn't have compatibility issues with Objective-C. By moving the implementation to Objective-C, I avoided the Swift-to-Objective-C bridging issues. This works fine when the classes are added manually to the project.
However, packaging it into a framework presents additional challenges. The key steps I followed to resolve this issue in the framework were:

Objective-C Category for WKScriptMessageHandler: Instead of directly handling WKScriptMessageHandler in Swift, I implemented a category in Objective-C to ensure compatibility, as WKScriptMessageHandler is fully supported in Objective-C.

Bridging Between Swift and Objective-C: I made sure that the category properly bridges between the Swift framework and the React Native integration using RCT_EXTERN_MODULE and RCT_EXTERN_METHOD. This avoids the issues that arise from the auto-generated -swift.h file and the incorrect interpretation of WKScriptMessageHandler.

Framework Packaging Considerations: When packaging this into a framework, make sure that all relevant Objective-C headers are properly exposed and included in the umbrella header of the framework. This ensures that any class or protocol from the category is accessible when the framework is integrated into a project.


By following this approach, I was able to package the framework successfully while maintaining full compatibility for handling WKScriptMessageHandler within the React Native project.
I hope this helps anyone facing similar issues—it took quite a bit of effort, but this solution worked for me!
